# Position Image over top line of div

Tags: html, css

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish: http://prntscr.com/8idhoz

As you can see, I'm trying to get an image over the top line of the div - I've managed to achieve this by using `position: absolute`, but is there another way?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="box">
<br>
<img src="image.png" style="position: absolute; top: 185px; left: 690px;" />
<h2>Heading</h2>

.box {
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; 
}
```

Comment: Why do you need another way? .. Do you mean with less html code or skipping the img tag or ...

Comment: I need the div's to do quite a lot of moving around, and with position: absolute, the images stay.. absolute.

Comment: is your current code is messing with other codes and layout.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should work :)

```css
.box {
 margin-top:100px;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000; 
}
img{
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<br>
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f0267fed40b9c4ea8dba326e22562fa8?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
<h2>Heading</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!